# Does the formal power series $\frac{x^2}{1-x^2} + \frac{x^4}{1-x^4}+\frac{x^8}{1-x^8}+\cdots$ have a name?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, number-theory, terminology, formal-power-series

Define a formal power series like so:
$$P_2(x) = \frac{x^2}{1-x^2} +  \frac{x^4}{1-x^4}+\frac{x^8}{1-x^8}+\cdots$$

I rigged the definition of $P_2$ so that the sequence of coefficients of $x^i$ looks like this:

$$0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,\ldots$$

This sequence comes up in number theory. If we ask how many factors of $2$ occur in the numbers $1,2,3, \ldots$, we obtain the above sequence.

More generally, define $$P_p(x) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{x^{p^i}}{1-x^{p^i}}.$$

If I'm not mistaken, the corresponding sequence of coefficients arise as the number of factors of $p$ in the numbers $1,2,3,4, \ldots$.

> **Question.** What are these formal power series really called?

*Remark.* My original question was edited under the mistaken premise that these are not formal power series. In fact, they are. For instance, since $1-x^2$ is a non-zero formal power series, hence so too is $\frac{1}{1-x^2},$ which is by definition the unique $Q \in \mathbb{R}(x)$ such that $Q(1-x^2) = 1$, which turns out to be $$Q = 1+x^2+x^4+\cdots.$$ Furthermore, $\mathbb{R}(x)$ carries a topology, which allows us to take limits; under this viewpoint $P_2(x)$ is a limit of partial sums, and this sequence of partial sums is convergence, $P_2(x)$ is a perfectly good formal power series. And, in future, please don't edit my questions to reduce interpersonal conflict. The OP can edit their own question themselves if they realize they're wrong. And if they're not wrong, I'd much prefer that he/she stands their ground aggressively, which is, after all, *much* more admirable than backing down when you're right.

Comment: For every $|x|>1$, $$P_p(x)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\nu_p(n)x^{-n}$$ where $\nu_p(n)$ denotes the $p$-adic valuation of $n$ (the highest power of $p$ which divides $n$). For example, $$P_2(x)=-(x^{-2}+2x^{-4}+x^{-6}+3x^{-8}+x^{-10}+\cdots)$$

Comment: Your series is a geometric series plus a [Lambert series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_series).

Comment: @Did, I don't see how that could be true. Can you elaborate?

Comment: "My original question was edited under the mistaken premise that these are not formal power series. In fact, they are." They were not. Formal power series have a value at $x=0$, yours had not.

Comment: "I don't see how that could be true" How *what* "could be true"?  Did you check the definition of `the p-adic valuation` function?

Comment: @Did; I don't get your top comment. This question is (and as far as my view of the edits made tells me, has always been) about a power series in _positive_ powers of $x$, not in negative powers. So I don't see what all those minus signs are about. It is true that there was an error in the constant terms not being suppressed initially, but to deduce from that error that OP meant a series in $x^{-1}$ and not in $x$ seems rather a leap.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Not a leap if you think about it, but the simplest way to make sense of the initial version of the question, which asked for a series expansion of $$\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac1{1-x^{p^n}}$$ This is not a series in $x$ but a series in $t=x^{-1}$ hence, if you prefer to phrase it this way, the series of interest is $$\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac1{1-t^{-p^n}}=-\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac{t^{p^n}}{1-t^{p^n}}$$ that is, minus times the series in the current version of the question. No mystery here, is there?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure it has a specific name, it's basically the [ordinary generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#Ordinary_generating_functions) of the 2-adic valuation, with the only difference that you take $x^{-n}$ in the formula rather than $x^n$ (this is sometimes done for convenience).

If you want a name, I'd go with *$2$-adic (ordinary) generating function*. I don't think it's got any well-established name.

Comment: 2-adic sounds like a chemical suffix